# Can't lauch google-chorme-stable. Getting Out of date NSS (Libnss3) on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome

This is with Ubuntu 16.04, with libnss3 3.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.01 installed. It looks like the prior ticket, which was closed for an out of date Ubuntu, missed that it also applies for 16.04.

Comment: How did you install chrome?

Comment: What errors  do you get? Any picture, any message...?? When you run `google-chrome` at terminal, What is the output?